# В чем отличие cstdio от stdio.h

Tags: c++

Вероятно заголовок моего вопроса звучит глупо. Но, у меня вопрос следующего рода: [в данном видео](https://youtu.be/6_9NFJOZp9o?t=1636) (27:15-27:50) человек решает задачу и говорит, что большая часть времени занимает сугубо ввод и вывод. А далее вместо `#include <cstdio>` пишет `#include <stdio.h>`, и меняет тип выводимой переменной с `%lld` на `%I64` и это ускоряет программу аж в 2 раза. Почему данные действия ускорили программу?

Ссылка на задачу из видео: https://acmp.ru/asp/do/index.asp?main=topic&id_course=2&id_section=20&id_topic=46

Comment: Есть код в текстовом виде и ссылка на проверяющую систему?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ссылку на задачу оставил, однако код в данный момент я предоставить не смогу, ввиду того, что хотел сам эту задачу решить и немного помучать ее и прочувствовать. Поэтому я не очень хотел бы переписывать код из видео. И вообще мое думание над этой заадчей может затянуться надолго...

Comment: Тут разница только с работой компановщика,   но не должно  быть существенной разницы по времени, если даже к этому добавить  сравнение флагов.  Не могу представить где это может быть полезно кроме оптимизации других частей кода.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Программу компилировали MinGW. Он может использовать две разные реализации `printf`:

- от майкрософта
- свою самодельную (дальше буду называть ее "ANSI")

Похоже, что первый вариант быстрее. Но он не умеет как минимум в `%lld` (поэтому на видео используют нестандартный `%I64d`) - поэтому и сделали альтернативную версию.

Экспериментально выяснил, что выбор между ними происходит так:

| Язык | Хедер | Вариант |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C | `<stdio.h>` | `-std=c90` и старее -> MS `-std=c99` и новее -> ANSI |
| C++ | `<stdio.h>` | `-std=c++98` -> MS `-std=c++11` и новее -> ANSI |
| C++ | `<cstdio>` | всегда ANSI |

Проверял на MSYS2. Без явного указания стандарта, у меня всегда выбирался ANSI - потому что дефолтный стандарт достаточно новый.

Можно переопределить выбор варианта, используя `-D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=0` и `1` (MS и ANSI соответственно), или `#define __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO 0` и `1` (до инклудов).

Проверить, какой вариант используется, можно `#if __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO == 1`.

---

Поскольку дефолтное значение зависит от стандарта, выбирать его через разные варианты хедера (как на видео) - выглядит ненадежно. Если для вас это важно, лучше явно задавать `__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO`.

---

Если интересно, то логика, угадывающая дефолтное значение, тут:

[`_mingw.h:423`](https://github.com/mingw-w64/mingw-w64/blob/0e0eed62328177b31a54023d9e3dad7bc12c0fd0/mingw-w64-headers/crt/_mingw.h.in#L423-L435)

```
/* We are activating __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO for various define indicators.
 * printf ll modifier (unsupported by msvcrt.dll) is required by C99 and C++11 standards. */
#if (defined (_POSIX) || defined (_POSIX_SOURCE) || defined (_POSIX_C_SOURCE) \
     || defined (_ISOC99_SOURCE) \
     || (defined (__STDC_VERSION__) && __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L && __MSVCRT_VERSION__ < 0xE00) \
     || (defined (__cplusplus) && __cplusplus >= 201103L && __MSVCRT_VERSION__ < 0xE00) \
     || defined (_XOPEN_SOURCE) || defined (_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED) \
     || defined (_GNU_SOURCE) \
     || defined (_SVID_SOURCE)) \
    && !defined(__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO)
/* Enable __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO if user did _not_ specify it explicitly... */
#  define __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO            1
#endif
```